# How to configure Lucene (SOLR) internal caching - memory issue/leak?

Tags: caching, memory, solr, lucene, out-of-memory

I am using SOLR 4.4.0 - I found (possible) issue related to internal caching mechanism.
JVM: -Xmx=15g but 12g was never free.
I created heap dump and analyze it using MemoryAnyzer - I found 2 x 6Gb used as cache data.
In second time I do the same for -Xmx12g - I found 1 x 3.5Gb
It was always the same cache.
I check in source code and I found:

```
  /** Expert: The cache used internally by sorting and range query classes. */
  public static FieldCache DEFAULT = new FieldCacheImpl();
```

see http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.apache.lucene/lucene-core/4.4.0/org/apache/lucene/search/FieldCache.java#FieldCache.0DEFAULT

This is very bad news because it is **public static** field and it is used in about 160 places in source code.

MemoryAnalyzer say:

> One instance of "org.apache.lucene.search.FieldCacheImpl" loaded by
>   "org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader @ 0x58c3a9848" occupies
>   4,103,248,240 (80.37%) bytes. The memory is accumulated in one
>   instance of "java.util.HashMap$Entry[]" loaded by "".
>
> Keywords java.util.HashMap$Entry[]
>   org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader @ 0x58c3a9848
>   org.apache.lucene.search.FieldCacheImpl

I do not know how to manage this kind of caches - any advice?

And finally I got OutOfMemoryError + 12Gb of memory is blocked.

Answer (score 1):

I implemented kind of workaround:

I created this kind of class:

```
public class InternalApplicationCacheManager implements InternalApplicationCacheManagerMBean {

    public synchronized int getInternalCacheSize() {
        return FieldCache.DEFAULT.getCacheEntries().length;
    }

    public synchronized void purgeInternalCaches() {
        FieldCache.DEFAULT.purgeAllCaches();
    }
}
```

and registered it in JMX via **org.apache.lucene.search.FieldCacheImpl**

```
    ...
          private synchronized void init() {
    ...
            initBeans();

          }

          private void initBeans() {
              try {
                  InternalApplicationCacheManager cacheManagerMBean = new InternalApplicationCacheManager();
                  MBeanServer mbs = ManagementFactory.getPlatformMBeanServer();
                  ObjectName name = new ObjectName("org.apache.lucene.search.jmx:type=InternalApplicationCacheManager");
                  mbs.registerMBean(cacheManagerMBean, name);
              } catch (InstanceAlreadyExistsException e) {
...
              }
          }
...
```

This solution provide you invalidate internal caches - which solve partially this issue.
Unfortunately there are other places (mostly caches) where some data is stored and not removed as fast as I expect.

Answer (score 0):

If you use FieldCacheRangeFilter you may wanna try range filters which work without field cache. If sorting is an issue, you may try using less sort fields or ones with a data type using less memory.

The field cache for each reader/atomic reader is thrown away when the reader is garbage collected. so a re-initialization of the reader should clear the cache which also means that the first operation using the cache will be a lot slower.

Fact is: FieldCache based range filter and sorting relies on the cache. There is no getting around when you really need those. You only can adapt your usage to minimize the memory consumption.

Comment: How I can minimize the memory consumption? 
Even I unload specified collections, data loaded into cache during query execution is not released from SOLR.

Comment: Not using fieldcacherangefilter, not using sorting or lessen the amount of sort fields, change the sort field types, e.g. from long to int if possible.

Comment: ok but it sounds like not solution for this issue - everything is working fine but SOLR is not releasing cached data (even I unload collection). I will investigate it more deeply.

Comment: what do you mean by "collection"? lucene will never release the cache as long the readers exist. that's why i'm saying, you can only release the cache, when closing and removing the readers. don't know the internals of solr.

Comment: OK. I got you. It means the issue is probably related to SOLR (not Lucene). Thanks!